# Huge data set Cursor Based Pagination with Web API & SQL Server queries

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, pagination

I have a table with 30 Million records & we are using SQL server queries to pull the data.

```
SELECT FruitName, Price
FROM SampleFruits
ORDER BY Price
OFFSET 5 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

With above approach with Offset (page) & Fetch (rows) we are having issues with performance, as Offset needs to scan all the records until the offset number it is causing issues.

I was looking at different options & I see the recommendation with large data set is Cursor based pagination. How do the cursor based pagination looks like in SQL query, we should include Previous & Next Page in query itself to send it to consumers and what would be the parameters look like ?.

How does the query looks like to give prev & next in the result set ?

```
{  
    Fruits:[  
        {  
            name: "Oraange",  
            shelfLife: "2021-06-15",  
            weight: "30 Lbs"  
        },  
        ...  
    ],  
    nextPage: "?",  
    previousPage: ?,
    totalRecords: ?
}
```

In Web API where do we set the nextPage & previousPage in the query or form it at the business layer in C# ?

Getting totalRecords is a separate query ?

When they want to go backwards do we need to change query to set previousPage, nextpage. **Basically how query looks like in Cursor based pagination in SQL server and where does the nextpage & previousPage are set in sql query or done in C#. Also, what are query parameters to the Web API ?**

Comment: See [Keyset Pagination](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset)

Comment: Seems the comment and answer already contain all info. If you need only next and prev (not navigation to specific page number) just do " > last id" query on next and "< first id" query on previous navigation (last and first ids are of rows you have on the current page).

Comment: I can't believe that with a table of 30 million records your users would ever fetch more than 10-20 pages at the most. If this is the case then you may want to think about an approach that only retrieves a few hundred rows.

Answer (score 1):

The normal recommendation is to:

- Never fetch `totalRecords`, as it's often more expensive than fetching the pages.
- Use a paging query of the form

Like this:

```
SELECT top (@rows) FruitName, Price
FROM SampleFruits
WHERE ID > @lastId
ORDER BY Price, ID
```

Passing the last ID from the previous page to get the next page, and always making sure the ORDER BY is unique, and supported by an index.

Comment: thank you.. Where do I form the next page & previous page URL's in the C# logic ? and if I use previous page link should I do ID < "@lastId" instead of > "@lastid" ? and what are the query params, I think "@rows" are how many rows we may need, "@lastId" is the another one which would do ID > "@lastId", but when user want to navigate back how do we go back ? I am assuming https://myapplication/fruits?rows=25&lastId=1001 is the URL but how Id determine lastId for Prev & next link to form in Json and return to users ?

Comment: What is that Prashant ? it's not related to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will understand if you read here, under "cursor-based pagination"
https://daily.dev/blog/pagination-in-graphql

the cursor should be a unique and ideally able to order, like Id or datetime, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.

Comment: I removed your question. You can move it into a comment here, if you want to offer more discussion. The answer without that question seems a link with an appropriate summary, i.e. a decent answer for StackOverflow. Have fun.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29990484)